# Add public IP to only one NIC (Azure)

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-azure

I'm creating several VMs through for_each, but only one must have a public IP address.
How can I do that?
It is understandable how that can be done with count, but what is the way for for_each?

main.tf

```
variable "vms" {}

resource "azurerm_network_interface" "nics" {
  for_each            = var.vms
  name                = each.value.nic
  location            = var.resource_location
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.rg.name

  ip_configuration {
    name                          = "nic-${each.value.name}"
    subnet_id                     = lookup(azurerm_subnet.subnets, each.value["subnet_id"], null)["id"]
    private_ip_address_allocation = "Dynamic"
    public_ip_address_id          = azurerm_public_ip.ext_ip.id (BUT ONLY FOR THE FIRST VM IN LIST)
      }

}
```

terraform.tfvars

```
vms = {
  vm1 = {
    disk_size = "30"
    name      = "vm1"
    nic       = "nic-1"
    sku       = "7_9"
    subnet_id = "snet1"
    username  = "centos"
    vm_size   = "Standard_B1ms"
  }
  vm2 = {
    disk_size = "35"
    name      = "vm2"
    nic       = "nic-2"
    sku       = "7_9"
    subnet_id = "snet2"
    username  = "centos"
    vm_size   = "Standard_B1ls"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the following approach, you can prepare a map of conditional public ip's and then create the resource based on that.

variables.tf

```
variable "vms" {
 type = map(object({
  #...
  public_ip  = optional(bool)
 }))
}
```

locals.tf

```
 pips = { for k, vm in var.vms : k => {
    # add required attributes to generate public ip resource
    } if vm.public_ip == true
  }
```

main.tf

```
 resource "azurerm_public_ip" "public_ip" {
    for_each = local.pips 

    # ...
  }

resource "azurerm_network_interface" "nics" {
   for_each = var.vms
  # ...

  ip_configuration {
  #...
  public_ip_address_id = try(azurerm_public_ip.public_ip[each.key].id,null)
 }
}
```

Comment: I got the idea with optional, but how it will look with actual reference to the azurerm_public_ip resource? To assign IP I need to get its ID from azurerm_public_ip.xxx.

Comment: I've edited my answer - I think a better approach would be to build a map of public ips to create beforehand (in locals) and then reference them dynamically.

Comment: Thank you! The second approach works! The first one shows an error in syntax after if.